# Tab completion like in Textmate?

Tags: vi, vim

I want to be able to use tab completion in Vim like in Textmate.

Like this.

- Running `<Tab>` should switch between words in the current document, starting with the closest one.
- Suggestions should be shown inline, not in a list.

It would be great if it, when out of words in the current file, could loop through words from a dictionary.

I'm using [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) at the moment, is it possible to tweak it to meet my needs?

Here is the related code from my vimrc file.

```
function! Tab_Or_Complete()
  if col('.')>1 && strpart( getline('.'), col('.')-2, 3 ) =~ '^\w'
    return "\<C-N>"
  else
    return "\<Tab>"
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <C-R>=Tab_Or_Complete()<CR>
set dictionary="/usr/share/dict/words"
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's be clear.

Hitting `<tab>` in TextMate doesn't provide word completion at all, it triggers the expansion of snippets.

Word completion using the content of the current file is triggered by hitting `<Esc>`.

Semi-intelligent code completion can be provided by the currently active bundle, most often using `<Alt><Esc>`.

That's three types of completion with three different shortcuts and three very different UIs and behaviours.

Now on Vim's side…

Some plugins (SnipMate, SnippetEmu…) are designed to provide an equivalent of TextMate's `<Tab>` expansion system.

Word completion is provided by a built-in feature called "insert mode completion" (`:help ins-completion`) and is triggered by hitting `<C-n>` or `<C-p>` or `<C-x><C-k>` to complete from a dictionary.

Code completion is provided by a built-in feature called "omni completion" (`:help new-omni-completion`) and triggered by hitting `<C-x><C-o>`.

I don't think you want to mimick TextMate's `<Tab>` expansion or perform code completion.

That leaves us with a mix of

- `<C-n>` or `<C-p>` to complete with words from the current buffers
- `<C-x><C-k>` to complete from your dictionary

Comment: Is it possible to hide the autocompletion list when using `<C-n>` ?

Comment: You can also use the abrev commands to add abbreviations, which expand to the full form upon typing a 'non-word' such as space or tab.